# ¿Librerías Java para Drones Wifi?

Tags: java

Bueno, recién encontré que hay una App llamada WifiUFO, que sirve para controlar drones y trasmitir vídeo en tiempo real, solo hay que conectarse al Wifi del Dron desde el celular, mi pregunta es ¿Como podría conectarme desde un lap con una Apliacion  en JAVA y poder controlarlo y trasmitir vídeo?

empezando por enviar datos desde java a un modulo Esp8266,¡ existe alguna librería?

el dron al que quiero conectarme es un LeadHonor X19

Comment: Jesus, tu pregunta es extremadamente amplia y podría terminar en espera o cerrada. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta para que concuerde con [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Es un estudio completo sobre el protocolo de comunicacion, al parecer existen dos involucrados [MAVLink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAVLink) y comunicacion en frecuencia 2.4G para WiFi, si existen librerias, pero para Java me ha convencido Yadrone. Hay un enlace [aqui](https://studiofreya.com/2016/01/27/how-to-program-a-drone-with-java/) a un tutorial que podria resolver tus preguntas.